# Multiple case statements/Multiple Update statement

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

can you please tell me how can I use the CASE statement with multiple cases on the same Column?

```
update FRIDAY.Joined_table
SET
Cost = CASE WHEN Channel = 'SEA' THEN Paid_Costs ELSE Cost END,
Clicks = CASE WHEN Channel = 'SEA' THEN Paid_Clicks ELSE Clicks END,
impressions = CASE WHEN Channel = 'SEA' THEN Paid_Impressions ELSE Impressions END,
Cost = CASE WHEN Channel = 'Performance-Display' THEN DBM_Costs ELSE cost END
Where New_Ids IS NOT NULL
```

"Here it tells me : Update item Cost assigned more than once at [6:1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
update FRIDAY.Joined_table
SET
Cost = CASE WHEN Channel = 'SEA' THEN Paid_Costs 
WHEN Channel = 'Performance-Display' THEN DBM_Costs ELSE Cost END,
Clicks = CASE WHEN Channel = 'SEA' THEN Paid_Clicks ELSE Clicks END,
impressions = CASE WHEN Channel = 'SEA' THEN Paid_Impressions ELSE Impressions END
Where New_Ids IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

Below is an alternative option that eliminates redundancy in expressing CASE statements and looks cleaner and easier to manage

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE FRIDAY.Joined_table t1
SET 
  cost = x, 
  clicks = y, 
  impressions = z
FROM FRIDAY.Joined_table t2,
UNNEST([
  CASE channel 
    WHEN 'SEA' THEN STRUCT(paid_costs AS x, paid_clicks AS y, paid_impressions AS z)
    WHEN 'Performance-Display' THEN STRUCT(dbm_costs AS x, clicks AS y, impressions AS z)
    ELSE STRUCT(cost AS x, clicks AS y, impressions AS z)
  END 
  ]) val
WHERE TO_JSON_STRING(t1) = TO_JSON_STRING(t2)
```

nothing comes for zero price - so, there is self join here :o(

To address this - below is yet another option

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION CASE_UPDATE(t ANY TYPE) AS (
  CASE t.channel 
    WHEN 'SEA' THEN STRUCT(t.paid_costs AS x, t.paid_clicks AS y, t.paid_impressions AS z)
    WHEN 'Performance-Display' THEN STRUCT(t.dbm_costs AS x, t.clicks AS y, t.impressions AS z)
    ELSE STRUCT(t.cost AS x, t.clicks AS y, t.impressions AS z)
  END  
);
UPDATE FRIDAY.Joined_table t 
SET 
  cost = CASE_UPDATE(t).x, 
  clicks = CASE_UPDATE(t).y, 
  impressions = CASE_UPDATE(t).z
WHERE TRUE
```

To further streamline above can be finally written as (assuming you know what type you use for updated columns , like INT64, or FLOAT64 / NUMERIC, etc.)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION CASE_UPDATE(t ANY TYPE) 
RETURNS STRUCT<cost FLOAT64, clicks INT64, impressions INT64>
AS (
  CASE t.channel 
    WHEN 'SEA' THEN STRUCT(t.paid_costs, t.paid_clicks, t.paid_impressions)
    WHEN 'Performance-Display' THEN STRUCT(t.dbm_costs, t.clicks, t.impressions)
    ELSE STRUCT(t.cost, t.clicks, t.impressions)
  END  
);
UPDATE FRIDAY.Joined_table t
SET 
  cost = CASE_UPDATE(t).cost, 
  clicks = CASE_UPDATE(t).clicks, 
  impressions = CASE_UPDATE(t).impressions
WHERE TRUE
```